# How to show images in a slanted way

Tags: html, css

[image: image slanted way]

How can I display my images and videos slanted like shown in example.

I could not do this using
`transform: skewY(-15deg);`
As with the skew it will skewed in the same direction on the top and bottom but I want it to slant upward from the bottom and downward from top.
Also as it can be viewed, the image is slightly titled
How can I acheive this

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what 'slightly titled' means? As for the rotation, explore CSS 3D transforms.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/how-css-perspective-works/?

Comment: use css transform rotate

Comment: [3D specific CSS properties](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms#3d_specific_css_properties).